# Changing spatial reference of Map using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, aprx

Steps:

1. I am loading an aprx from a template, which is in WGS84 spatial
   reference.
2. Then I do some processes.
3. Finally, I want to **change
   the MAP's spatial reference (WGS84)** to another, which I get from another layer.

Is it possible to do it **using arcpy** and **ArcGIS Pro**?

The code is:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"\\ptemplate\project.aprx)

ras= "my_layer.tif"

sr=arcpy.Describe(ras).spatialReference

aprxMap = aprx.listMaps()[0]
```

How do I change the Spatial Reference to `_sr_`?

```
aprx.saveACopy(r"\\my_projects\project_out.aprx)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're pretty much there with your code. You just need to apply the SR on the map

```
ras= "my_layer.tif"
sr=arcpy.Describe(ras).spatialReference

p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"\\ptemplate\project.aprx")
m = p.listMaps()[0]
m.spatialReference = sr
p.saveACopy(r"\\my_projects\project_out.aprx)
```